# One Deck Dungeon Paladin Heroic Feat

Tags: untagged

The text of the Heroic Feat for the Paladin states “Store a (Heroic Die) here when you open a door with 4+ (XP). You may only store one die at a time.”

What does “with 4+ XP” mean?

1. Does it mean the door has to have a loot of 4 XP? But Loot isn’t specified.
2. Does it mean that I have to have 4+ XP on my character?

And if it’s the second option, does this mean that if I’m level 2 (which costs 6 XP), that I have to get 4 XP after starting that level before I can once again get the die, or do I always get it? That seems a little too easy, so I’m guessing not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Paladin's ability triggers when you open (flip) a door card and reveal a monster or peril worth at least 4 XP.**

The "with" in the description applies to the door card, not to your character, so having 4 XP in your possession won't trigger anything.

The description also doesn't mention taking the card as loot as it triggers when the door is first opened or flipped to reveal the contents. You do not have to stay and encounter the monster/peril and can choose to flee after gaining the Heroic die. Note that if you return later, the ability will not trigger again as the door is already open.